# Why is Outlook application.Session null?

Tags: vsto, outlook-redemption

`application.Session` is null but should have an object, and does for other users on the same machine.

When trying to access `Globals.ThisAddIn.outlookApplication.Session` I get a NullReferenceException on `application.Session`.

```
Redemption.RDOSession session = Redemption.RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
session.MAPIOBJECT = Globals.ThisAddIn.outlookApplication.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
```

The same add-in works for other users on the same machine. This callback is hit from a click event on a ribbon button in Outlook. The user has a logged in session with Exchange and can interact with Exchange server normally.

Comment: Is that an inspector or explorer button? In the former case, was Outlook already running and connected to the mailbox?

Comment: Inspector ribbon button.  Outlook is already running and connected to Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

This issue ended up being a corrupt user.settings file.